Error generating SAS url for nodejs using azure storage
I am trying to generate a SAS url that I can send back to the client so that client can use the url to PUT the file directly into storage:
Following is the endpoint:(update 1):
   router.get('/get-upload-url', async (req, res) => {
     const blobName = 'dummyBlobName.jpeg';

     const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net`, new StorageSharedKeyCredential(ACCOUNT_NAME, SAS_TOKEN));
     const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(CONTAINER_NAME);
     const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

     const startDate = new Date();
     const expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
     expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 100);

     const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
       containerName: CONTAINER_NAME,
       blobName,
       permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse('cw'),
       startsOn: startDate,
       expiresOn: expiryDate
     }, blobServiceClient.credential);

     const sasUrl = `${blockBlobClient.url}?${sasToken}`;

     res.json({ sasUrl });
   });

   app.use('/', router);

   app.listen(PORT, () => {
     console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
   });

And the curl command I am trying:
curl -X PUT -T ~/Downloads/dp.jpeg \
-H "x-ms-date: $(date -u)" \
-H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" \
"https://appstrolabstoragedev.blob.core.windows.net/imgx/dummyBlobName.jpeg?sv=2024-08-04&st=2024-07-29T12%3A52%3A55Z&se=2024-07-29T14%3A32%3A55Z&sr=b&sp=cw&sig=jsYb6VOm57avYu2eS2H26Q6vMkzSjdnjMI%2B80xygQ%2F8%3D"

Error I am getting:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:beee57d1-201e-005b-7db6-e1f5de000000
Time:2024-07-29T12:53:12.7097016Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was cw
2024-07-29T12:52:55Z
2024-07-29T14:32:55Z
/blob/appstrolabstoragedev/imgx/dummyBlobName.jpeg
2024-08-04
b
</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>% 

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I want to create a URL, send it back to frontend so that client can use it to upload files directly to azure blob storage.
Error after updating blobName to 'dummyBlobName.jpeg'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:03849c77-001e-0087-46c0-e15f80000000 Time:2024-07-29T14:06:41.0301691Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was cw 2024-07-29T14:05:50Z 2024-07-29T15:45:50Z /blob/appstrolabstoragedev/imgx/dummyBlobName.jpeg    2024-08-04 b       </AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>%


The reason you are getting this error is because you are generating a SAS token for a blob named dummyBlobName.txt, however you are uploading a different blob (dummyBlobName.jpeg) using that token.
When generating a SAS URL for the blob resource (sr=b), the blob name must match. To fix this issue, please create a SAS token with dummyBlobName.jpeg blob name.
Other option would be to create a SAS token for the blob container (your SAS token will have signed resource as c). Then you can use that SAS token to upload any blob in that container.

fixed the issue. now getting:
RequestId:03849c77-001e-0087-46c0-e15f80000000
Time:2024-07-29T14:06:41.0301691Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was cw
2024-07-29T14:05:50Z
2024-07-29T15:45:50Z
/blob/appstrolabstoragedev/imgx/dummyBlobName.jpeg



2024-08-04
b






</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>% 


Please update your question and add the revised code. Please do not overwrite the existing code in the question.

@Arnob - it's very difficult to read code or data in a comment, as it's not formatted properly. Be sure to edit your question if you have more details to share.

updated @GauravMantri

You still have a different blob name in your curl command. Please make sure that both name matches.
